# Cant install Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I'm going through https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu and get error on installing Jenkins:

[terminal snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTXla.png)

java --version:
openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

I tried purging jenkins and java, tried using different versions of Java, still same result

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of logs, error messages, etc. Just copy the relevant information and paste it into your question. When you're asking people to help you, it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible to do so.

Comment: `See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`. Did you?

Comment: Also, check permissions on jenkins dir.